# Unable to create the storage directory every time I clear the cache inside docker container

Tags: php, symfony, docker, caching

I am working at a Symfony 3.4 application, using docker.
The problem is that after I enter in the container and do

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

I always have this cache problem:

```
Unable to create the storage directory (/var/www/app/var/cache/dev/profiler).
```

I know that I can solve it by using:

```
chmod 777 -R var/cache/* var/logs/*
```

But after I clear the cache again, the problem is still there.
There is a way to add just a single time the permissions, and after I clear the cache this issue to be solved?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Ensure that, in the *Dockerfile*, you create the cache directories needed by Symfony and set the right permission on them:

```
USER root
# RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data    # fix the UID
RUN mkdir -p var/cache/prod var/cache/dev var/cache/test var/log \
   && chown -R www-data:www-data var/ \
   && chmod -R ug+rwX var/
```

Then rebuild your image and the permissions on `var` should be fine by default and `www-data` should be able to write to the cache

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to solve this. Personally I use to run my development docker containers as the same user I use locally.

So all files are only owned by one uid (1000 in my case)

Another way fixing it would be ACL flags on /var/cache to inherit directory rights on creation automatically. This is described here: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/file_permissions.html

Comment: I am not sure how to add this in the docker file. 
Currently I have:

# Set the permissions on the volumes & generated dirs
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/app/var/cache/ &> /dev/null
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/app/var/logs/ &> /dev/null
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/app/var/sessions/ &> /dev/null
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/app/vendor/ &> /dev/null

Comment: just use `USER` directive. Maybe you'll need to create a new user first.

Comment: Do you want a dev setup or a production ready image holding all code?`

Comment: Could you share Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: I want to not need to set permissions to cache/log everytime I clear cache in the docker container.